# How to choose between 2 functions in an onchange event?

Tags: javascript, html, function, syntax, onchange

What is happening here is that when my webpage loads then it fires off a function called: `updatebrand`(). In this function there is a function called `updatestyle`() and is fired off in an onchange event.

This is great and it works but now once the webpage loads and I change the brand then another function is triggered called `updatenewbrand`(), this gets called and within this function is a function called `updatenewstyle`() which gets called on the onchange event.

I want to be able to say if `updatebrand`() gets triggered then run `updatestyle`() onchange, else if `updatenewbrand`() then run `updatenewstyle`() `onchange`().  I have some code below but I don't think I am doing it right? Please help.

```
<SELECT NAME="styles" id="styles"">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"><FONT CLASS="sm"><B>- Select Style -    
</B></FONT></option>

<SCRIPT>

var x = document.getElementById("styles");
x.onchange = function() {
if (x.value == "updatebrand") { //or whatever condition you want to run
    updatestyle();
} else if (x.value == "updatenewbrand") {
    updatenewstyle();
}
}
<?

--some other code is here

oci_close($connect);
?>

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: You can not have deprecated FONT tags or any tags in an option.

Comment: `options` can contain only text, you have placed html inside it.

Comment: okay thanks for that, I'll take that out, that's not what is causing it not to work though.  Can someone look at the other code and let me know how to go about fixing it.

Comment: If you're using this where I think you are, change the variable `x` to something more specific (since this is basically a copy paste of the answer I gave you on your other question). Same name variables can cause issues

Comment: Thanks RUJordan, I tried this but it is not working, I get no error but it doesn't do anything either?  It has to be something in the syntax I'm assuming.  I removed the 'X' and used 'getFunc' as the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Just test `this.value` instead of `x.value` since `x.value` is only set when the script loads and won't change.

Using `this` will get the current value any time the `onchange` event is fired.

```
var x = document.getElementById('first');

x.onchange = function() {

    switch(this.value) {
        case "updatebrand" :
            alert('Thing one.');
        break;

        case "updatenewbrand" :
            alert('Thing two.');
        break;
    }

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wm38h/2

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, this is what I have now and nothing happens:                                                                  <SELECT NAME="styles" id="styles">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"><B>- Select Style </option>

<SCRIPT>
 var getfunc = document.getElementById("style");
getfunc.onchange = function() {
switch(this.value){
     case "updatebrand" : //or whatever condition you want to run
     alert('Thing one');
     break;
     case "updatenewbrand" :
     alert('Thing two');
     break;
   
}
}
</SCRIPT>